# Icon doesn't change when navigating in a custom navigation bar (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, bottom-navigation-bar

In my flutter app I created a custom bottom navigation bar with the ability to change its icon when navigating using it, but when I used a FloatingActionButton to navigate, it navigate me to the correct spot but the color of the icon of the page didn't changed.

After I tried many things to solve this problem I found that when I perform a quick reload to the app the icon change to be correct. So, I want to know what can I do to let the Icon change by itself when I navigate using a FloatingActionButton?

**Here is the code:**

```dart
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          pageIndex.value = 1;
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = 1;
          });

          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
        child: Icon(
          //CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble_fill,
          CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble_fill,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 30,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
```

```dart
class _BottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const _BottomNavigationBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.onItemSelected,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final ValueChanged<int> onItemSelected;

  @override
  State<_BottomNavigationBar> createState() => _BottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarState extends State<_BottomNavigationBar> {
  void handleItemSelected(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
    widget.onItemSelected(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        top: false,
        bottom: true,
        child: Container(
          color: sColor,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              bottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "Messages",
                icon: CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble_2,
                iconFilled: CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble_2_fill,
                index: 0,
                isSelected: (selectedIndex == 0),
                onTap: handleItemSelected,
              ),
              bottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "contacts",
                icon: Icons.contacts_outlined,
                iconFilled: Icons.contacts,
                index: 1,
                isSelected: (selectedIndex == 1),
                onTap: handleItemSelected,
              ),
              bottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "Search",
                icon: CupertinoIcons.search,
                iconFilled: CupertinoIcons.search_circle_fill,
                index: 2,
                isSelected: (selectedIndex == 2),
                onTap: handleItemSelected,
              ),
              bottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "Me",
                icon: CupertinoIcons.person_crop_circle,
                iconFilled: CupertinoIcons.person_crop_circle_fill,
                index: 3,
                isSelected: (selectedIndex == 3),
                onTap: handleItemSelected,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

```dart
class bottomNavigationBarItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const bottomNavigationBarItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
    required this.icon,
    required this.iconFilled,
    required this.index,
    this.isSelected = false,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String label;
  final IconData icon;
  final IconData iconFilled;
  final int index;
  final ValueChanged<int> onTap;
  final bool isSelected;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () {
        onTap(index);
      },
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        height: 50,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Icon(
              isSelected ? iconFilled : icon,
              size: 25,
              color: isSelected ? seconderyColor : textColor.withOpacity(0.4),
            ),
            /*  const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Text(
              label,
              style: isSelected
                  ? const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11,
                      color: seconderyColor,
                    )
                  : TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11,
                      color: textColor,
                    ),
            ), */
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Here is the Scaffold of the main Screen were i put the NavigationBar:**

```dart
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: primaryColor,
      bottomNavigationBar: _BottomNavigationBar(
        onItemSelected: (i) {
          pageIndex.value = i;
        },
      ),
      body: Container(
        
        child: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: pageIndex,
          builder: (BuildContext context, int value, _) {
            return screens[value];
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

*I hope anyone can find helpful solution for my problem.*

Answer (score 0):

Icon color change when selected item in custom navigation bar

update your code

```
  bottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Messages",
             icon: Icon(item.iconData,color: selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.grey)
            iconFilled: CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble_2_fill,
            index: 0,
            isSelected: (selectedIndex == 0),
            onTap: handleItemSelected,
          ),
```

Comment: That will change the color of the icon but i meant that i want to change from normal icon to a filled version of the same icon

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the issue is possibly occurring because your BottomNavigationBarItem is a stateless widget which means that once it is rendered on to the screen, it will not change it's state. To make it accept changes to it's state, you should convert it to a statefull widget and properly manage the state.
After converting it to statefull widget, do the following change in your handleitemselected function

```
void handleItemSelected(int index) {
  setState(() {
    selectedIndex = index;
  });
  widget.onItemSelected(selectedIndex);
}
```

I hope this helps, if it does vote it up